# Computer not working, motherboard is suspect

Tags: motherboard

I have a problem with my computer. I have a GeForce 6100 M9 Motherboard, which I suspect is broke. The capacitors beside the CPU are corroded and the computer doesn't do anything except start the fans when I push the power button. The problem is that I can't find another motherboard as they apparently don't sell this model anymore. I have tested the Power Supply and it appears to be working. Any advice would be appreciated.

Different forums have mentioned that you can replace the capacitors. Any help on this would be appreciated.

What is the most similar motherboard that I can get and how hard would it be to swap them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blown capacitors are pretty indicative of a bad motherboard.  Any kind of "mushroom top" or leaking fluid will make things no longer work.

You don't need the exact same model of motherboard, (although it is a bit easier for drivers and such) you just need on that supports your CPU, and Ram.. (and type of hard drive and video card, if its an older on, such as PATA, or VGA video)

Comment: Will I be able to stick a new motherboard in and run the computer just like that without reinstalling windows?

Comment: Careful-- If you're running windows, sometimes you run into licensing and validation issues when replacing motherboards because to Microsoft, new motherboard=new computer.

Comment: Even if it is the same motherboard model?

Comment: yes. You should be able to re-activate the product though.

Comment: @Arlen - If it's identical, it will probably be okay.  Even if it isn't, assuming it's close enough you should be able to get Windows to a usable state with a minimum of driver fuss.  Worst case is that you have to reinstall.  (And it may trip activation, but usually you can just reactivate with no trouble.  Even if it won't reactivate, calling up the activation hotline and explaining the problem to the agents will always get you a new activation code - MS is very easy on XP these days.)

Comment: All that said, that's a socket 939 board and those haven't been in active use for three or four years.  You're probably better off doing what CarlF says and just buying a new machine.  (Unless you feel very comfortable with a soldering iron, you won't be replacing capacitors.)

Comment: Problems is that I still have all my old data to worry about, plus compatibility of programs, etc (should be fine there, though). Is there any way to keep the programs running the way they were? I assume I can add the current drive as a slave and copy everything over that I need.

Comment: If you're using a software raid, that might be a conflict too.

Comment: In general, if your new motherboard has the same kind of disk bus (e.g. SATA) you can just hook up the new drive and copy data over, or use an external enclosure if not. *HOWEVER, you should be backing up any important data regularly in any case* and if you aren't, you should start.

Answer (score 3):

I promise, people still sell motherboards.  If you mean that your particular form factor isn't available, consider that a new case would only cost $25 and up.  Consider also that a new computer, with warranty, can be found for $300.

Comment: I mean model, not shape.

Answer (score 0):

Since the motherboard is the backbone, when the desktop comes up, windows will just think you have all new hardware and re-install all hardware connected to it.

HOWEVER, sometimes windows will not boot (probably because of a difference in IDE drivers/RAID etc). *IF* you have a boot issue  (such as IRQ_NOT_LESS_EQUAL stop error),  you can get it back up and running without total loss of data.

I call it the "second R" recovery option. Where you pick THE SECOND "r" from the windows bootable disc setup screens. The first one which you don't want to select is for recovery console. Pick the second r, DON'T reformat or reconfigure the disc, tell it to reinstall into the same windows folder.

When it is back up, you should have your registry intact and all your programs and user profile intact.

Comment: Where can I get a Windows disc.